# Custom Camera with surface view issue in android

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I am Working on one barcode scanner application.
my barcode scanner and surface view works perfectly. but, **while maintaing aspect ratio of camera, parent view layout is cut slightly from bottom in higher version android devices like nexus and motog as shown in first image.** in lower version android devices i didn't face  this issue like micromax canvas.

Here are two images,
in 1st image, 1st tab containing Camera view, and parent view cut slightly from bottom during maintaing aspect ratio of camera and in 2nd image of 2nd tab it's look perfect.

[image]  [image]

Here is my cameraPreview class,

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

private PreviewCallback previewCallback;
private AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera,
        PreviewCallback previewCb, AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCb) {

    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    previewCallback = previewCb;
    autoFocusCallback = autoFocusCb;

    // supported preview sizes
    mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters()
            .getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);

    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
    // preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        // Log.d("DBG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Camera preview released in activity
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    /*
     * If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
     * Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
     */
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes
    // here
    // start preview with new settings
    try {

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
        mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log.d("DBG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),
            widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(),
            heightMeasureSpec);

    if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width,
                height);
    }

    float ratio;
    if (mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
        ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
    else
        ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

    // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview
    // slightly
    setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
    // setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w,
        int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

    if (sizes == null)
        return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;

        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    return optimalSize;
}
```

}

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a little solution for this, 
i still didn't get what is the really issue was, but i just set padding for my frame layout as below in which i am adding surface view, and it's resolve my issue.

```
android:padding="0.2dp"
```

and my framelayout as below in wihch i am adding surface view,

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_frameScanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/color_black"
        android:padding="0.2dp" >
    </FrameLayout>
```